# Would early stages of leadership lead to dictatorship?

Tags: government

**Scenario**:
A new civilization is born. People are emerging from their wandering lifestyle to the settled agriculture and trade based survival. We could assume that they'd implement a town centre and start administrative operations. This could be of various sorts such as:

- Resource management
- Keeping records
- Managing population

I'm assuming this could only begin by an *individual's* initiative rather than with a group coming forward with everything planned ahead. If this is the case, how would the leadership evolve in the future? When would it distribute power and make *formal laws*? Is this a likely scenario compared to the formation of a democracy from the very first?

If it is possible for a group to initiate the town's governance, how would it implement its power?

Comment: What are the backgrounds, individual and collective, of the people involved?  Were they all colonists from some single place, for instance?  What prior governance have they lived under?  How have they done things in the past?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Wouldn't it gather up to a huge amount of data? Are they all necessary?

Comment: I think "what system of government would a group of people naturally come up with", which seems to be the core of your question, depends a lot on what forms of government the people involved have already experienced.  You're not asking about newly-hatched people with no prior experiences, right?

Comment: If you're looking for a semi-plausible scenario under which tribal oligarchy turns into dictatorship, look at Frazer, *The Golden Bough*, chaps 3-4 (esp. 4). This is by no means usual, but he makes it plausible.

Comment: @MonicaCellio In that case this is a bad question, isn't it? I shall delete this.

Comment: @RenaeLider I wouldn't jump straight to deletion.  It feels broad now, but if you add some details (doesn't need to be a tome, just key points) about the your particular situation, I think it could do fine.  (Note that I *didn't* vote to close; I'm just asking for a little more info.)

Answer (score 6):

That's a bit of an oversimplified view of civilization. If I understand your premise properly, you're talking about small tribes or nomads gathering together to found a town.

### Leadership is not dictatorship

First of all, they would already have some form of leadership. Even tribes and small groups have de facto leaders, established either by consensus (people just seem to go to them for questions or guidance in daily matters and they have everyone's trust) or by heritage (the chief's offspring become chiefs in their own right and people are fine with it).

While this resembles, in the modern political sense, a dictatorship, it is in practice very far from it. Dictatorships have and require a huge distance from the low rungs of society - town leadership is rarely that far removed, unless it is supported by a more powerful authority. In a mere town, what kind of dictatorship could you have? And if your concern is for the longterm implications of that model, there is nothing to indicate what the future political structure will be, either way. Pretty much every early civilization had de facto leaders in the local sense and grew within a strict monarchy. It was only millennia later that some form of *official* recognition of public will was established within political structures.

### Politics hasn't always worked the same

Even this is oversimplification. Under ancient monarchies, the general will of the people *was* taken under consideration - monarchs and leaders who ignored it where considered *unjust* and where unliked, no matter their authority, power or the effects of their actions. Again, even *after* the need to reflect public opinion was established, it was a *long long* time until we had anything resembling modern democracy. The ancient greek and roman republics where heavily aristocratic and only the rich could really vote - 9/10 of the population had no say in anything. It was just a glorified lobbyistic monarchy.

### Nope

Considering the above and how recent the notion of a "dictatorship" really is, I'd say no, it doesn't lead to any kind of dictatorship. It would be a long time before there was authority far removed from most people and it would probably be centuries or millennia until public representation was a clear ingredient in political systems in order to make *ignoring it* (a dictatorship) an ingredient as well.

Overall, it's impossible to tell how a civilization will develop just by observing its early stages - *especially* when we have so few examples to work with. It could develop in all kinds of ways depending on events, contact with other cultures, social reforms, who knows.

### Scales

The formation of democracy straight up is nearly impossible - there is a simple reason: the problem it solves has not been detected or defined yet. Until then, you have implicit and de facto leaders - that structure happens in small groups due to efficiency and division of labor; until it is proven to be ineffective (which in our civilization happened only a few centuries ago), it will be maintained to the bitter end.

Also, your impression that a city can *only* be started by the initiative of one person, is in conflict with how communities and cities form in general. People aggregate to cooperate better - when there's more people, there's more hands to work and less work for everyone, because work and its yield don't scale linearly. That's why you get tribes in the first place. Often, cities spring up where resources are, because everyone goes there - they also emerge around mines, fields, factories etc. . It has to do with proximity and the efficiency of communities, not initiative. From an individual's point of view, cities just *happen*.

Comment: Does this imply that democratic system has no advantage over the other(s)?

Comment: @user3058846 Obviously not - I'm saying a democratic system, like any other system, needs work to come about. Before that work can be put in though, a society needs to recognize that there is political inadequacy or that the system is problematic, have enough time to come up with an weigh alternatives, attempt to establish the most popular ones and it will still take time for people to properly understand what system they're under, just like with any political structure. I'm saying that democracy isn't a choice if you don't know it exists.

Answer (score 3):

In some sense, almost every system of government can be equated to a dictatorship to some degree, in that it is necessary for the area and populace governed to abide by the rulings of the government in order to maintain stability.

Since the question does not specify that this is a *human* government, I will begin by assuming a human government, then discuss the options for non-humans.

Humans in small tribal societies are typically governed by groups of elders, who by their years of experience, can remember situations in the past corresponding to current situations.  As settlements grow beyond a single tribe, and as trade increases in volume, it becomes necessary to keep records.  It is from such a necessity for record keeping that writing is invented or imported.  In the early days of a society's adventure into literacy, only a few individuals will be literate, and not necessarily the leaders.

Since in this scenario, a single tribe has had an influx of people from other tribes, there would still be multiple leaders.  A single leader is unlikely to arise without some sort of external stimulus such as a war, since any tendency toward dictatorial behavior would simply lead to the populace leaving for a place with a less unreasonable leadership, or removal of the would-be dictator.

In the event of a war, however, it is of benefit to a society to have a single overall military leader, as this reduces the duration of the decision cycle and ensures that response times to threats are minimized.  Societies that have experienced large-scale war are more likely at that point to develop a monarchy and an aristocracy based on military position, as humans tend to want to retain whatever authority they gain.

In fact, outright totalitarian dictatorships amongst humans are pretty rare.  It takes a strong-willed and ruthless individual to achieve and maintain such a position, and such people are often the subject of assassination attempts and rebellions, so most forms of government that remain functional over time take some notice of the opinions and needs of the population that they govern.

As to alien societies, the psychology of the species must be taken into consideration.  A herd-based species may have many leaders, even if they practice a form of sexual dominance, as any individual spending time becoming the dominant member of their gender is almost by definition *not* spending it being a good administrator.  A dictator under these circumstances would be practically unthinkable.

An individualistic species would have forms of government not too dissimilar from humans if they had a tendency to be gregarious, but again a dictatorship would be unlikely to arise.

The traits that would most encourage a dictatorship would be a situation where the members of a species had some differences in intelligence levels, for example, if the old were much more intelligent than the young, or if there was a "brain" caste.  In such a situation, the best thinker would make a natural leader.

Answer (score 2):

This was covered to an extent in Diamond's "Guns, Germs, and Steel".

The ruler has as much power and latitude to rule, as the economic and survival conditions permit them. E.g. in subsustence-agriculture  or other resource-poor environment, there just isn't enough surplus to support a layer of "not doing anything useful for survival" ruling classes, nor to mention dictatorial methods of control (which require "muscle" to implement, who also have to be fed).

As there exists more surplus, game theory says that naturally those humans with leadership abilities will try and capture that surplus - both because they think they know better what to do with it, as well as to use it as means of control (both by paying off the enforcers, and by rewarding political supporters).

Would that lead to dictatorship? Depends on the species. In Earth Homo Sapient, that is a likely sceanario.

- ~3% of individuals classify as socio- or psychopaths.

  A person like that, when they do get power, will of course be more predisposed to more dictatorial and less democratic form of government
- basically, democracy is not a stable equilibrium. It's easy to slip out of it if the leadership is captured by power seeking sociopath; which is what happened to pretty much every attempt at Democracy; some faster (such as France to Communist Russia), some slower (Roman Republic, or even USA in its 2014 form; it would be seen closer to dictatorship than to a democratic republic by the Founders thanks to steady enroachment of executive power and legislative incumbency). As an alternative they fall to external forces (Athens lost to Macedonia).

Comment: It's not sociopaths that are the problem, its people seeking advantage and protection for those they love that are the real threat. Once people no longer see the interest of those they care for being aligned with the majority of the population, everybody just tries to save as much as they can by controlling as much as they can.

Answer (score 1):

There is a common opinion that relations between people largely depend on the technology owned by civilization, and revolutions mostly happen when technology advances enough to make the existing order inefficient, and the new order more efficient.

Almost always, there are some social groups that loose from this transition. With enough power they may stop the evolution, or force into sub-optimal branch of evolution, for a few hundreds years. However such forced deviation from the optimal path cannot last forever. When the ruling power applies some terminal already measures to keep the hopelessly failing current state, we call this dictatorship.

Hence if the new civilization starts really badly, with unsuitable personalities involved, this may create a few hundreds of "dark ages" but these will pass.